# How does SQLAlchemy create_engine import Engine class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am relatively new to python and am experimenting with SQLAlchemy. I noticed that, to create an engine, I have to use the `create_engine()` function, imported via `from sqlalchemy import create_engine`.

Now, the `create_engine` function returns an instance of the `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine` class. However I never imported this class, I only imported the `create_engine` module. So, how does Python know about the `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine` class?

Comment: The module you import that function from might've imported the needed class itself... Have a look: https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py#L68

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably don't understand what importing does.

Python imports modules *globally*. There is a single structure, called `sys.modules`, that stores imported modules as a dictionary:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules
{'builtins': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>, '_frozen_importlib': <module 'importlib._bootstrap' (frozen)>, '_imp': <module '_imp' (built-in)>, ...}
```

When you import SQLAlchemy, you import a *package*, a structure of multiple modules, where one import triggers more imports. All those imported modules are stored in that same place:

```
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> [name for name in sys.modules if 'sqlalchemy' in name]
['sqlalchemy', 'sqlalchemy.sql', 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression', 'sqlalchemy.sql.visitors', 'sqlalchemy.util', 'sqlalchemy.util.compat', 'sqlalchemy.util._collections', 'sqlalchemy.util.langhelpers', 'sqlalchemy.exc', 'sqlalchemy.util.deprecations', 'sqlalchemy.sql.functions', 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes', 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements', 'sqlalchemy.inspection', 'sqlalchemy.sql.type_api', 'sqlalchemy.sql.operators', 'sqlalchemy.sql.base', 'sqlalchemy.sql.annotation', 'sqlalchemy.processors', 'sqlalchemy.cprocessors', 'sqlalchemy.event', 'sqlalchemy.event.api', 'sqlalchemy.event.base', 'sqlalchemy.event.attr', 'sqlalchemy.event.registry', 'sqlalchemy.event.legacy', 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema', 'sqlalchemy.sql.selectable', 'sqlalchemy.sql.ddl', 'sqlalchemy.util.topological', 'sqlalchemy.sql.util', 'sqlalchemy.sql.dml', 'sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator', 'sqlalchemy.sql.naming', 'sqlalchemy.events', 'sqlalchemy.pool', 'sqlalchemy.log', 'sqlalchemy.interfaces', 'sqlalchemy.util.queue', 'sqlalchemy.engine', 'sqlalchemy.engine.interfaces', 'sqlalchemy.sql.compiler', 'sqlalchemy.sql.crud', 'sqlalchemy.engine.base', 'sqlalchemy.engine.util', 'sqlalchemy.cutils', 'sqlalchemy.engine.result', 'sqlalchemy.cresultproxy', 'sqlalchemy.engine.strategies', 'sqlalchemy.engine.threadlocal', 'sqlalchemy.engine.url', 'sqlalchemy.dialects', 'sqlalchemy.types', 'sqlalchemy.schema', 'sqlalchemy.engine.default', 'sqlalchemy.engine.reflection']
```

Once a module is loaded from disk and added to that structure, Python doesn't need to load it a second time. Dots separate module names in a hierarchy, so everything starting with `sqlalchemy.` lives inside the `sqlalchemy` package as a tree structure. There are a lot of `sqlalchemy` modules here, this is a large project, and they were all loaded (directly or indirectly) by the [root package module, `sqlalchemy/__init__.py`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/__init__.py).

The other thing `import` does is *bind a name in your current namespace*. Each module is a 'global' namespace, all names in that namespace are visible in that namespace. Your Python script is imported as the `__main__` namespace, and all names in it are available to your script. If you create a module `foo`, then that is a separate namespace with their own names. `import` adds names to your global namespace from another module. And in Python, names are *just references*; the actual objects each of these names reference all live on a big pile in memory, called the *heap*.

The line

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

first makes sure that the object `sys.modules['sqlalchemy']` exists, and adds the name `create_engine` to your current namespace, a reference to `sqlalchemy.create_engine`, as if the line `create_engine = sys.modules['sqlalchemy'].create_engine` was executed:

```
>>> sys.modules['sqlalchemy'].create_engine
<function create_engine at 0x10188bbf8>
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> create_engine is sys.modules['sqlalchemy'].create_engine
True
```

Again, all names in Python are *just references* to a big pile of objects in memory.

When you call the `create_engine()` function, the code for that function is executed, and that function has access to all the globals in the namespace it was defined in. In this case the function is defined in the `sqlalchemy.engine` module (the top-level `sqlalchemy` module itself has imported it as `from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine` so you can access it from a more convenient location):

```
>>> create_engine.__module__
'sqlalchemy.engine'
>>> sys.modules['sqlalchemy.engine']
<module 'sqlalchemy.engine' from '/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py'>
>>> sorted(vars(sys.modules['sqlalchemy.engine']))
['BaseRowProxy', 'BufferedColumnResultProxy', 'BufferedColumnRow', 'BufferedRowResultProxy', 'Compiled', 'Connectable', 'Connection', 'CreateEnginePlugin', 'Dialect', 'Engine', 'ExceptionContext', 'ExecutionContext', 'FullyBufferedResultProxy', 'NestedTransaction', 'ResultProxy', 'RootTransaction', 'RowProxy', 'Transaction', 'TwoPhaseTransaction', 'TypeCompiler', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'base', 'connection_memoize', 'create_engine', 'ddl', 'default', 'default_strategy', 'engine_from_config', 'interfaces', 'reflection', 'result', 'strategies', 'threadlocal', 'url', 'util']
```

That list of names are all the names defined in the same module as `create_engine` is defined in. The module was already loaded by code executed when you imported the `sqlalchemy` module. The function has access to all those and can return you any such object. You'll note that the is a `Engine` name defined there:

```
>>> sys.modules['sqlalchemy.engine'].Engine
<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>
```

So that object is *already loaded into Python memory*. All the function does is create an instance of that class for you and return it:

```
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
>>> engine
Engine(sqlite:///:memory:)
>>> type(engine)
<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>
```

If you want to learn more about Python and names, I recommend you read Ned Batchelder's essay on [*Facts and myths about Python names and values*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: So do I understand it correctly that the from x import y:

(1) makes x (and everything contained in x) available for me using sys.modules, if x does not yet exist, independent of what y is.

(2) just gives an easy to use name to x.y for me to use within my script

Comment: @JorenSips: yes, *and* adds one or more names to your current namespace. So `import foobar` makes sure that `foobar` is loaded (only needed once), and then adds a name `foobar` to your current namespace that's a reference to the module object. `from foobar import spam` will make sure `foobar` is loaded if not already there, then adds the name `spam` to your current namespace, which is a reference to the object that `foobar.spam` references. You can add `as ...` to those statements to adjust what name is used.